# Browser is not downloading excel file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I'm using Apache POI for generating excel file in my spring mvc application. here is REST API:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/export-companies",
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Timed
    public void downloadCompanies(HttpServletResponse response) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample Sheet");

        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("TEST");

        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.xlsx");

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        workbook.write(byteArrayOutputStream);
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", "" + byteArrayOutputStream.size());
        response.setContentLength(byteArrayOutputStream.size());
        workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
    }
```

At front end (I'm using Angular JS):

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('MyApp')
        .factory('CompanyExportService', CompanyExportService);

    CompanyExportService.$inject = ['$resource'];

    function CompanyExportService ($resource) {
        var service = $resource('api/export-companies', {}, {
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: false
            }
        });

        return service;
    }
})();
```

But download is not initiating at browser.

Comment: And why should it? You are issuing an AJAX request, so that is also the one that receives the response. You should have a success handler for your service to handle the download. If you want to browser to handle it, just make a regular link (also imho you should be downloading using a GET not a POST but that might be just me).

Comment: thanks. I've made a regular link which is doing fine.